# React-Native init with template from private registry

Tags: react-native, templates, dependencies, package, github-package-registry

Someone know if it's possible to use a react-native template from a private registry, like Github Packages?

```
react-native init myproject --template mytemplate
```

if my template is published on github packages, how I tell to react-native to get it from there?

Also,
If this template also contains a package hosted on private registry, I know that puting .npmrc at project root make it works, but inside react-native cli, it will work too? And it will work with yarn or I need to uninstall it to react-native-cli use only npm?

Answer (score 0):

Yep, we do it at our company. Like so:

`npx react-native init my project --template=https://github.com/myorg/mytemplate`